# Django raising a TemplateDoesNotExist at /web/edit/

Tags: python, django, server, module, server-error

The HTTP is giving me the `ModuleNotFoundError` whichever link I go.

The `ModuleNotFoundError` is giving me the following information:

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /url/

No module named 'django.core.context_processors'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/web/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'django.core.context_processors'
Exception Location: <frozen importlib._bootstrap>, line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Python Executable:  /Users/william/Documents/coding/WDTP/wfw_fixed/env/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.9.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/william/Documents/coding/WDTP/wfw_fixed/wfw',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/william/Documents/coding/WDTP/wfw_fixed/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 23 Jan 2021 00:07:14 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this import to `from django.template.context_processors import csrf`. Your current import seems to be depreciated (via https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.8/#django-core-context-processors )